# Can i install Oracle on a VirtualMachine within Ubuntu Desktop 14.0

Tags: 14.04

Is it possible to install Oracle 12g on a VirutalMachine using Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.1? I heard it was not possible, but these are different versions, any feedback will be greatly appreciated. The purpose for this is to test Oracle 12g within Ubuntu VM. Your time is greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/470349/installing-oracle-database-12c-on-ubuntu-14-04 .  I think 12c is the latest.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you actually want it to be usable or not :-) I'd suggest a VM of at least 4 cores and 8 GB. Configure plenty of swap space because OUI has some rather antique ideas about this.

Start with this article, old now but good:
http://www.pythian.com/blog/oracle-silent-mode-part-110-installation-of-102-and-111-databases/

Oracle DB silent installation is your friend.

The oracle installer makes some checks about target system configuration, which you can either bypass or modify by using the command line. One parameter I've found very useful to manipumate is MemoryPercentage, default is 30 or 40% of you system memory, but for testing only you can wind it down to 10 or 15, as long as Oracle has access to the minimim amount of memory it needs which used to be around 1GB with 10 and 11, might be more now.

Under VBox your IO will probably suck so don't expect to win any TPC benchmarks. But it should at least start and work.

Comment: Sorry misread the question. I've not tried this under ubuntu VM but have tried it under various other virty technologies. I can't think of a reason it wouldn't work under ubuntu vm.