# Error in invoking target 'all_no_orcl' of makefile '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, oracle

ERROR while installing oracle 12c in ubuntu 14 LTS. Stuck at 59%.

Error:

> Error in invoking target 'all_no_orcl' of makefile
>   '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'. See
>   '/u01/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2015-10-10_09-31-56PM.log'
>   for details.

**installActions2015-10-10_09-31-56PM.log:**

```
INFO: Start output from spawned process:
INFO: ----------------------------------
INFO: 

INFO: chmod 755 /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin

INFO: rm -f oracle dbv tstshm maxmem orapwd dbfsize cursize genoci extproc extproc32 hsalloci hsots hsdepxa dgmgrl dumpsga mapsga osh sbttest expdp impdp imp exp sqlldr rman   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/dg4odbc mkpatch /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/dg4adbs /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/dg4db2 /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/dg4ifmx /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/dg4ims  /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms
INFO: /lib/dg4msql   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/dg4sybs /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/dg4tera /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/dg4vsam nid adrci wrc extjob extjobo jssu genezi kfod amdu kfed uidrvci diskmon setasmgid renamedg orion asmlg skgxpinfo drdactl drdalsnr drdaproc /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/ksms.s /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/ksms.o

INFO: 

INFO:  - Linking DB*Verify utility (dbv)

INFO: rm -f /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/dbv

INFO: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/orald -o /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/dbv -m64 -z noexecstack -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -L/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/ -L/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/ -L/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/stubs/   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/s0kudbv.o  -ldbtools12 -lclntsh -lclntshcore -lsnls12 -lunls12 -lnls12 -lclntsh -lclntshcore  `cat /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/ldflags`    -
INFO: lncrypt12 -lnsgr12 -lnzjs12 -ln12 -lnl12 -lnro12 `cat /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/ldflags`    -lncrypt12 -lnsgr12 -lnzjs12 -ln12 -lnl12 -lnnz12 -lzt12 -lztkg12 -lztkg12 -lclient12 -lnnetd12  -lvsn12 -lcommon12 -lgeneric12 -lmm -lsnls12 -lnls12  -lcore12 -lsnls12 -lnls12 -lcore12 -lsnls12 -lnls12 -lxml12 -lcore12 -lunls12 -lsnls12 -lnls12 -lcore12 -lnls12 `cat /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/ldflags`    -lncrypt12 -lnsgr12 -lnzjs12 -ln12 -lnl12 -lnro12 `cat /u01/app/oracle/product
INFO: /12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/ldflags`    -lncrypt12 -lnsgr12 -lnzjs12 -ln12 -lnl12 -lclient12 -lnnetd12  -lvsn12 -lcommon12 -lgeneric12   -lsnls12 -lnls12  -lcore12 -lsnls12 -lnls12 -lcore12 -lsnls12 -lnls12 -lxml12 -lcore12 -lunls12 -lsnls12 -lnls12 -lcore12 -lnls12 -lclient12 -lnnetd12  -lvsn12 -lcommon12 -lgeneric12 -lsnls12 -lnls12  -lcore12 -lsnls12 -lnls12 -lcore12 -lsnls12 -lnls12 -lxml12 -lcore12 -lunls12 -lsnls12 -lnls12 -lcore12 -lnls12   `cat /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/sysliblist` -Wl,-r
INFO: path,/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib -lm    `cat /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/sysliblist` -ldl -lm   -L/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib -laio

INFO: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -laio

INFO: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

INFO: make: *** [/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/dbv] Error 1

INFO: End output from spawned process.
INFO: ----------------------------------
INFO: Exception thrown from action: make
Exception Name: MakefileException
Exception String: Error in invoking target 'all_no_orcl' of makefile '/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk'. See '/u01/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2015-10-10_09-31-56PM.log' for details.
Exception Severity: 1
```

Comment: And what's in `/u01/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2015-10-10_09-31-56PM.log`?

Comment: Thats what I have added

Answer (score 2):

The error the `make` is getting appears to be:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -laio
```

So your Ubuntu installation is probably missing `libaio`, which is used for asynchronous I/O support in the kernel.

I think you can install that by running:

```
sudo apt-get install libaio1
```

Someone else has put a guide together for installing Oracle 12c on Ubuntu 15.04 in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/654197/452099). That (particularly the list of packages to install before Oracle) might help you get it running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Ubuntu is not in the list of [supported Linux distributions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LTDQI/toc.htm#BABBCJAA) for Oracle 12c, so I would be reluctant to use this as a production system, or even a development system if I wanted my production and development systems to match.