# How to install Oracle http server 12c on ubuntu 18.04 server?

Tags: server, software-installation, 18.04, oracle

How can I install  Oracle http server 12c on Ubuntu Server 18.04?

Comment: Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470349/installing-oracle-database-12c-on-ubuntu-14-04) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168522/how-can-i-install-oracle-11g-r2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Oracle database 12c on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470349/installing-oracle-database-12c-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Oracle 11g R2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168522/how-can-i-install-oracle-11g-r2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the [Oracle HTTP Server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/webtier/downloads/index.html).
2. Extract it in `/stage` then move to the *stage* folder (`cd /stage`)
3. Run `sudo chmod +x fmw_12.2.1.3.0_ohs_linux64.bin`
4. Run `./fmw_12.2.1.3.0_ohs_linux64.bin`
5. Follow the [installation steps](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/identity%20management%2012c/oam%2012c%20(12.2.1.3)/getting_started_series/6-configureohs/index-template.html) on Oracle's official website.

Comment: Does oracle hhtp unpack to `/stage` ? Not just `stage` in the folder where you did the unpack ?